# How to make Grafana get metrics for a external url?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm configuring a new additional scrape config to make prometheus scrape a external url (outside of my k8s cluster) like this:

```
  - job_name: my-scrapes
    scrape_interval: 30s
    scheme: https
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['mydomain.com']
    metrics_path: /some-path/metrics
```

I'm able to find this job in the Prometheus service discovery and on targets:
[image]

[image]

The metrics are publicly exposed, so no problem with being behind a proxy. The question is how can I make Grafana exhibit these metrics in its UI dashboard since is not a pod in the local cluster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add your prometheus as a data source in grafana. Did you try it?

Comment: Yep, Grafana is already being able to get metrics from all other stuff that are within my cluster, the source metrics is Prometheus, the problem is with this little one that is outside the cluster, which is a URL exposing the metrics

Answer (score 0):

Grafana does not check the prometheus targets.
So if your prometheus targets are inside or outside your cluster, this does not change anything for Grafana.

The only thing that is important here is that Grafana has access to your datasource. In your case, it's Prometheus.
So if Grafana can access Prometheus, then you will be able to query any metrics available in Prometheus within your Grafana dashboard.

Comment: Ok, but I'm no able to find it in any Grafana dashboards, I'm a little confused. Grafana is getting metrics from pods within my whole cluster. But I need that Grafana gets the metrics publicly exposed from this URL. Since it's not a local cluster pod, how grafana will exhibit this to me?

Comment: Is it Prometheus or the target scraped by it that is not in the cluster ? Does Grafana have access to Prometheus ? If not, then you won't be able to show the metrics in Grafana

Comment: Prometheus and Grafana are in the same k8s cluster and can talk with each other, Grafana is already showing me all the metrics from pods within the cluster. The URL exposing the metrics is outside the cluster, but the metrcis is publicly accessible

Comment: Then if you can see the metrics within Prometheus, you should be able to see them in Grafana. If not, it's probably due to an error in your dashboard